# Generating 100 million integers using Python

Tags: python, random

I am writing an application to generate 10 thousand to 100 million integers and I am unsure whether a .txt file is the right representation to hold the integers. Below is my code:

```
import random
def printrandomInts(n,file):
    for i in range(n):
        x = random.random();
        x = x * 10000000
        x = int(x)
        file.write(str(x))
        file.write("\n")
     file.close()

file = open("10k","w")

n = 10000
printrandomInts(n,file)
file = open("100k","w")
n*=10
printrandomInts(n,file)
file = open("1M","w")
n*=10
printrandomInts(n,file)
file = open("10M","w")
n*=10
printrandomInts(n,file)
file = open("100M","w")
printrandomInts(n*10,file)
```

When I run the above code, the size of the largest file Windows reports is 868,053 KB. Should I use binary representation to efficiently represent the integers. I also have to generate similar data for floats and strings. What should I do to make things more space efficient?

Comment: It depends on how you want to *use* them.  Do you know what you want to do with them?  How do you plan to do it?  The most compact way to represent them is as binary data.  You could also use a specific random seed and generate the data on demand as a stream, avoiding the need for a file.  Again, how do you want to use it?

Comment: I am using the data to find the number of occurrences of the ints so generated. Something of the sort "Integer" --> "Number of times integer appears in data".

Comment: Well, in that case you could save some memory by counting them as soon as you generate them, then discard the raw data.  It looks like the numbers will be in the range 0 through 9,999,999, a range of 10,000,000, so if you want to count them all, you'll probably need an array that big.  Now ask yourself, after counting them, what do you then want to do with the results?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are the counts for later analysis you can use @TomKarzes 's idea of counting them as you generate them, along with using the [pickle module](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) for storing them:

```
import random, pickle

counts = [0]*10000000

for i in range(100000000):
    num = random.randint(0,9999999)
    counts[num] += 1

pickle.dump(bytes(counts),open('counts.p','wb'))
```

The file `counts.p` is just 9.53 MB on my Windows box -- an impressive average of a little less than 1 byte per number (the overwhelming majority of the counts will be between 5 and 15, so the stored numbers are on the smallish side).

To load them:

```
counts = pickle.load(open('counts.p','rb'))
counts = [int(num) for num in counts]
```

A final remark -- I used `bytes(counts)` rather than simply `counts` in the pickle dump because the chance of any count being greater than 255 is vanishingly small in this problem. If in some other scenarios the counts could be larger, skip this step.